# how to transform pandas dataframe based on index and one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as follows.

```
time          location         count
2022-05-01       A              1
2022-05-01       B              2
2022-05-01       C              3
2022-05-01       D              4
2022-05-02       A              5
2022-05-02       B              6
2022-05-02       C              7
2022-05-02       D              8
```

I want to transform the dataframe as below.

```
time          A     B     C     D
2022-05-01    1     2     3     4
2022-05-02    5     6     7     8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.pivot(index='time', columns='location', values='count')

location    A  B  C  D
time                  
2022-05-01  1  2  3  4
2022-05-02  5  6  7  8
```